# How do I call this function in a sproc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I got this function from someone on here:

```
    create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@s varchar(512),@sep char(1)) 
RETURNS table 
AS 
RETURN ( 
    WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS ( 
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s) 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1) 
      FROM Pieces 
      WHERE stop > 0 
    ) 
    SELECT pn, 
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s 
    FROM Pieces 
  )
```

Normally in where clauses of sprocs I call this type of function like this:

```
WHERE u.[Fleet] IN (SELECT [VALUE] FROM dbo.udf_GenerateVarcharTableFromStringList(@Fleets, ','))
```

How do I go about calling the above function in a similar manner?

Thanks!

Comment: You also may want to select the list into a table, and then select against the table. Functions in the where clause are typically evaluated with each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to replace [value] with [s].

Comment: hmm. this still passes nothing into my paramter when blank is coupled with a value....dang

Answer (score 1):

Since you said the result of:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString('abc,def', ',')
```

is correct, then it's likely that everything should work. Check what happens when you have an empty token (two adjacent commas) and see if the results are as you expect.

Also, I noticed there was an effective limit on how long the input string could be. Check to make sure that nothing is getting cut off.

Comment: column pn - row 1 = 1 row 2 = 2
coulnm s - row 1 = abc row 2 = def

Answer (score 0):

The function does not remove leading/trailing spaces, so if you have a string 'a, b, c' and a separator ',' you'll get a table with 'a', ' b', ' c'.  Does this match in your u.[Fleet]?